# Parse Xml Data in StringBuilder

Tags: android, xml

So iam using Reverse GeoCoding , everything work fine but i receive the response in the xml format packaged in StringBuilder

i am looking to get just One line eg. : i want item1 in a String , how can achieve this ?

Here is my code ;

```
 public void getPlaces() {

HttpURLConnection connection = null;
URL serverAddress = null;
Double latitude = 37.422006;
Double longitude = -122.084095;

try {
    // build the URL using the latitude & longitude you want to lookup
    // NOTE: I chose XML return format here but you can choose something else
    serverAddress = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + Double.toString(latitude) + "," + Double.toString(longitude) +
                "&output=xml&oe=utf8&sensor=true");
    //set up out communications stuff
    connection = null;

    //Set up the initial connection
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

    connection.connect();

    BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + '\n');
    }
    // now the response is packaged in a string,
    // parse the XML or whatever you need
    String responseText = sb.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}



}
```

Thanks .

Edit :
Solved Using this Link :

http://www.smnirven.com/blog/2009/10/09/reverse-geocode-lookup-using-google-maps-api-on-android-revisited/

Comment: change line in while block to this sb.append(line);

Comment: i just want to get 1-2 Item on the Xml Data , you say i should remove \n ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location using Geocoder

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lattitude,longitude, 1);
```

Comment: yes i know , but this is better using google beacause GeoCoder give me null result all the time

Comment: i dont know , when i was using it my wifi and gps were enabled , anyway the link i posted solved my issue and there is no problems